# How to display master-detail rows in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, master-detail

Is it possible to display master-child rows in Excel using C#?

For example, the first row has two children, so there will be a plus sign. When the user clicks it, the children are displayed.

Comment: Read your question back to yourself and ask yourself whether readers should have to guess all the missing parts of your description of the problem. If they do, will you get the best answer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with Pivot Tables. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/expand-collapse-or-show-details-in-a-pivottable-or-pivotchart-report-HP010175905.aspx